# String Matching

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, string

I have a string

```
String mainString="///BUY/SELL///ORDERTIME///RT///QTY///BROKERAGE///NETRATE///AMOUNTRS///RATE///SCNM///";
```

Now I have another strings

```
String str1= "RT";
```

which should be matched only with `RT` which is substring of string `mainString` but not with `ORDERTIME` which is also substring of string `mainString`.

```
 String str2= "RATE" ;
```

And `RATE`(str2) should be matched with `RATE` which is substring of string `mainString` but not with `NETRATE` which is also substring of string `mainString`.

How can we do that ?

Comment: *Why* should it match RT but not ORDERTIME? *Why* should it match RATE but not NETRATE?

Comment: What do you mean with "matched"; do you just want to check whether the strings are present?

Comment: @Jon Skeet,Sir because I want to know where in a string exact match is done ?

Comment: @Fredrik Mork,I want to know in mainString for which substring exact match is done.

Comment: But you haven't explain the rules by which you're trying to match. You've given examples, but not the rules they're meant to be examples of. You can use string.IndexOf to find out where a substring match occurs, but unless you can clarify what you're trying to do, that's not going to help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know it will work every time or not.But I have tried this and it works right now in this string matching. I want to know whether this is ok or not,please give me suggestion.

```
str1 = str1.Insert(0, "///");
str1=str1.Insert(str1.Length,"///");

bool Result = mainString.Contains(str1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Match against `"///RT///"` and `"///RATE///"`.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understand your question you want to match a string between `///` as delimiters.
if you look for `str` you just have to do
 `Regex.Match(mainString, "(^|///)" + str + "(///|$)");`

Answer (score 0):

This might give you some clues - no where near real code quality, and only a 5 minute job to come with this shoddy solution but does do what you need. it smells lots be warned.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace test {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            String mainString="//BUY/SELL//ORDERTIME//RT//QTY//BROKERAGE//NETRATE//AMOUNTRS//RATE//SCNM//";


            Hashtable ht = createHashTable(mainString);



            if (hasValue("RA", ht)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Matched RA");
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Didnt Find RA");
            }


            if (hasValue("RATE", ht)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Matched RATE");
            }


            Console.Read();

        }


        public static Hashtable createHashTable(string strToSplit) {
            Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
            int iCount = 0;

            string[] words = strToSplit.Split(new Char[] { '/', '/', '/' });
            foreach (string word in words) {

                ht.Add(iCount++, word);
            }

            return ht;
        }
        public static bool hasValue(string strValuetoSearch, Hashtable ht) {

            return ht.ContainsValue(strValuetoSearch);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: String.Split(char[]) splits on *any* of those characters - it doesn't treat it as a *sequence* of characters.

Comment: it does get a working hashtable with the individual items from the string enought to "find" the values

Answer (score 0):

What about Linq to Object?

```
String mainString="///BUY/SELL///ORDERTIME///RT///QTY///BROKERAGE///NETRATE///AMOUNTRS///RATE///SCNM///";
String searchTerm = "RT";
String[] src = mainString.split('///');
var match = from word in src where 
            word.ToLowerInvariant() == searchTerm.ToLowerInvariant() 
            select word;
```

I don't have VS near me so I can't test it, but it should be something similar to this.